# variable set in azure pipeline gets corrupted when read in template

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

variable big_var_01 defined with value '3q4w#V$X3q4w#V$X' by following azure pipeline yaml file gets corrupted to become value '3q4w#V#V'  when read back in azure pipeline template

```
cat parent_scott.yaml



variables:
- name: big_var_01
  value: ${{ parameters.big_var_01 }}


parameters:
  - name: big_var_01
    displayName: "this var wants to get written to then read by templates"
    type: string
    default: '3q4w#V$X3q4w#V$X'


# CI Triggers
trigger:
  branches:
    exclude:
      - '*'

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

# Release Stages
stages:

- template: child_scott_one.yaml
```

following azure pipeline template variable big_var_01 is read back however its value is corrupted and does not match above assignment

```
cat child_scott_one.yaml 


# Release Stages
stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: JA
    steps:
    - script: |
        echo "here is big_var_01  -->$(big_var_01)<-- "

        local_var_01=$(big_var_01)

        echo
        echo "here is local_var_01  -->$local_var_01<-- "
        echo
        echo "length of local_var_01 is ${#local_var_01}"
        echo


      name: DetermineResult
```

see run of above pipeline

https://dev.azure.com/sekhemrekhutawysobekhotep/public_project/_build/results?buildId=525&view=logs&j=54e3124b-25ae-54f7-b0df-b26e1988012b&t=52fad91f-d6ac-51fb-b63d-00fda7898bb6&l=13

see code at  https://github.com/sekhemrekhutawysobekhotep/shared_variables_across_templates

How to make the string variable big_var_01 get treated as a literal evidently its somehow getting evaluated and thus corrupted ... above code is a simplification of my actual azure pipeline where I get same variable corruption issue even when setting up a Key Value secret with value   3q4w#V$X3q4w#V$X   which gets corrupted when read back in a pipeline template

here is another pipeline run which explicitly shows this issue  https://dev.azure.com/sekhemrekhutawysobekhotep/public_project/_build/results?buildId=530&view=logs&j=ed5db508-d8c1-5154-7d4e-a21cef45e99c&t=a9f49566-82d0-5c0a-2e98-46af3de0d6e9&l=38  on this run I check marked ON pipeline run option:  "Enable system diagnostics" ... next I will try to single quote my shell assignment from the azure variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution ... it works if I single quote around the azure variable during bash shell assignment

```
local_var_01=$(big_var_01)    #  bad results with value  3q4w#V#V
local_var_02="$(big_var_01)"  #  bad results with value  3q4w#V#V
local_var_03='$(big_var_01)'  #  good this gives value 3q4w#V$X3q4w#V$X
```

my instincts said to not use single quotes knowing its not the bash shell way however once I accepted the fact azure performs some magic ~~helping~~ interstigal layer pre processing in between pipeline source code and fully resolved bash shell execution I took a chance and tried this ... come to find out this ***is*** how bash shell blocks variable expansion

Answer (score 0):

At some step Azure DevOps or Ubuntu replaced part of your string. So you have:

`3q4w#V$X3q4w#V$X` = `3q4w#V` + `$X3q4w` + `#V` + `$X`

and this part `$X3q4w` and  this `$X` was replaced with empty string giving you `3q4w#V` + `#V`.

If you run this with `\` before `$` like here `3q4w#V\$X3q4w#V\$X`

```
This is job Foo.
here is big_var_01  -->3q4w#V$X3q4w#V$X<-- 

here is local_var_01  -->3q4w#V$X3q4w#V$X<-- 

length of local_var_01 is 16
```

I got an error running this on `windows-latest` however I got correct string:

```
"This is job Foo."
"here is big_var_01  -->3q4w#V$X3q4w#V$X<-- "
'local_var_01' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
ECHO is off.
"here is local_var_01  -->$local_var_01<-- "
ECHO is off.
"length of local_var_01 is ${#local_var_01}"
ECHO is off.
##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '9009'.
```

so it looks like ubuntu replaces it with env variables however, since there is not variables like `$X3q4w` and `$X` it replaces with empty string.

Comment: believe me its not ubuntu doing any such madness its azure ... using bash on ubuntu properly handles string literal assignments where value is surrounded with single quotes ... above problem is when azure pipelines incorrectly pre-processes shell commands as it translates and interpolates from a pipeline into bash before executing on ubuntu ... I hope microsoft fixes this ... I am booking this on the azure forum